# DIAL with Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

Cobalt can default load the URL. We are investigating how to add the DIAL paring code to the URL. Maybe it needs a changeURL API for avoiding re-launching YouTube.

```
// Restrict navigation to a couple of whitelisted URLs by default.
const char kYouTubeTvLocationPolicy[] =
"h5vcc-location-src "
"https://www.youtube.com/tv "
"https://web-release-qa.youtube.com/tv "
```

[scenario]

1. launch YTTV with your remote controller
2. open YouTube app on your phone
3. try to pairing to TV

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt currently doesn't implement DIAL smooth-pairing once launched, but it does support being launched with alternate query parameters via the `--url=` command-line parameter.

For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/tv?...anything...
```

Will pass the navigation whitelist.

Full implementation of smooth-pairing support is planned for Q1 2017.

Comment: hi, david, now Q1 has been past, it seemed it can make smooth-pairing after that cobalt had launched and cast the video to the TV platform, but can not make smooth-pairing before cobalt started, but the Youtube test case has a dial wakeup test(https://sites.google.com/a/google.com/youtube-leanback-partners/testing/dialtesting), so dose cobalt have a plan to support it?

Comment: Hi, yes - the DIAL smooth pairing feature will be enabled in COBALT_9 when it is branched, which will be very soon. Note that the DIAL server, when launching Cobalt, needs to pass in the `additionalDataUrl` with the youtube URL (i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/tv?additionalDataUrl=...`) via the `--url` parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by DIAL wakeup - is this Wake on LAN ?

Comment: hi, david, the dial wake up test I mean is Wake on LAN, see the  youtube test case(https://sites.google.com/a/google.com/youtube-leanback-partners/testing/dialtesting), it need to start cobalt with youtube by dial. But in cobalt, dial server only work after that cobalt has been started, so it can not start youtube by dial at present in cobalt.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean. A device will need to wake up when it receives a DIAL launch request, and launch Cobalt with the additionalDataUrl. Why does this not work?

Comment: Oh, do you mean the in-app DIAL server? Yeah, that is only for devices they don't have a system DIAL server, which only applies to much older devices. So that won't be able to support WoL or other requirements...

Comment: hi, david, yes, the dial server I mean in the cobalt is in-app DIAL server, it's a NOT system dial server, thank you so much for your detail explanation.